# Does GLSL copy function arguments by value?

Tags: shaders, glsl

My question is about passing variables to GLSL shader. I'm not sure how that works and what are the performance implications.

Say I got a function that accepts a "vec4" variable. The question is - is that variable copied at the entrance? I guess it makes impact on performance if so. And if it happens to be that way is there a way to pass only references like in C/C++?

Comment: GLSL doesn't run on the CPU so you shouldn't think about it in the same terms as code that does run on the CPU.

Comment: This ^ comment is totally uninformative. Tell us how we *should* think about it, running on the GPU, then.. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GLSL always uses copying, but this doesn't have the same performance implications as C++. In particular, because there is no recursion, there isn't a stack, and typically either functions are inlined and optimized there by the GLSL compiler, or parameters are in fixed register locations and copying is unnecessary.

Note that passing by const& in C++ is completely different from "passing by reference." In passing by reference, the function is allowed to change the argument, and these changes are visible to the calling function. "`inout`" achieves a similar result, but is not quite the same as vec4& in C++ if you pass the same variable to different parameters of a function.

`vec4` is a primitive type in GLSL, you can expect it to behave like a `int` or `float` for performance. Finally, vec4 is only 128 bits, which is one or two cycles to copy.

Comment: Correction: In C++ passing by `const&` IS passing by reference. It's just a read-only reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the variable in the signature as "input". This will work as a reference pass (at least I'm the way you have asked).

Comment: this is actually not the case. The [GLSL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) states: > 6.1.1 Function Calling Conventions
>
> Input arguments are copied into the function at call time, and output
> arguments are copied back to the caller before function exit. 'in' is the default qualifier and will pass the argument by value.